# Is my class thread-safe with multiple threads accessing its variables?

Tags: java, concurrency, thread-safety, synchronized

As I am trying to get to grips with thread safety, I would like to know if this class is threadsafe? If two threads try to access its variables at any time it seems to me that it is thread safe because:

- final variable is threadsafe by virtue of being immutable.
- getter and setter are synchronized, so mObject can only be gotten, or set by one thread at a time. So there is no chance of two threads reading different values.
- The method changeObj() is not synchronized but any block in it which deals with class variables (i.e. mObject) is synchronized.

Please tell me if I am wrong or if this class is not threadsafe.

```
public class MyClass{

   private final String = "mystring"; //thread safe because final
   private AnObject mObject;

   public MyClass(){
       //initialize
   }

   //only one class can set the object at a time.
   public synchronized void setObj(AnObject a){
      mObject = a;
   }

    //two threads trying to get the same object will not read different values.
   public synchronized AnObject getObj(){
      return mObject;
   }

   //better to synchronize the smallest possible block than the whole method, for performance.
   public void changeObj(){
       //just using local variables (on stack) so no need to worry about thread safety
       int i = 1;
       //i and j are just to simulate some local variable manipulations.
       int j =3;
       j+=i;
       synchronized(this){
          //change values is NOT synchronized. Does this matter? I don't think so.
          mObject.changeValues();
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it's not thread safe. You make sure only one thread can change the values in your `AnObject` at a time if it uses the `changeObj()` method, but you also provide a getter for this object, so any other thread could call `changeValues()` concurrently.

Comment: If changeValues() were synchronized would this class then be threadsafe?

Comment: This is a good point. If the AnObject class is thread-safe, then the whole thing might still be thread-safe, but from context, it seems like it is not.

Comment: Making things synchronized doesn't magically make a class thread-safe. Either AnObject is thread-safe, and you don't need to have a synchronized block in the changeObj() method, or it's not, and you need to make sure that proper synchronization is used each time AnObject is used. Without encapsulating the instance completely (by using a copy constructor in the setter, for example, and by not providing any getter for this instance), this is very hard to guarantee.

Comment: Also, if `mObject` is mutable, you can also have thread-safety problems: `getObj().setSomeValue(foo);`

Answer (score 2):

Your class in itself is thread safe in its current state (assuming any methods not shown here are), however you have one likely "bug" in your thinking;

`mObject` isn't 100% encapsulated, it is passed in through a setter and can be fetched through a getter. That means that any thread could get a reference to and call methods on the object referenced by mObject simultaneously without MyClass knowing about it.

In other words, AnObject's methods may need to be thread safe too.

At the very least, the synchronizing in MyClass *doesn't in any way make mObject safe from threading problems*.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Mr. JB Nizet's points, if `AnObject.changeValues` is a method that is designed to be overridden by clients, or calls such methods, then this, in the general case, opens the door for various unwanted behaviours, like deadlocks and data corruption. You must never cede control to alien code within a synchronized block. By "alien" I mean code not under your control. More details can be found in Effective Java, 2nd Ed, Item 67.

Comment: How about making changeValues() final synchronized? Would MyClass be threadsafe then?

Comment: As I said, it depends on the implementation of `changeValues`. If it definitely does not call ony other methods that are designed to be overridden by someone else, then you are safe. This is a general point: you must have complete control over, or at least complete knowledge of, all the code involved in a critical section (a synchronized block).

Answer (score 1):

A final variable is not necessarily thread safe, only immutable final variables are thread safe -- that covers primitives and classes like `String`, or final variables of classes which themselves are thread-safe.

Your class is not thread safe because it exposes the variable `a`, but also requires it for its internal working.

The below example will demonstrate an example of how `a` could get into an inconsistent state.

Thread A

```
MyClass myClass = ...
myClass.changeObj(); 
// imagine Thread A is suspended during the synchronized block inside of 
// changeObj()
```

Thead B

```
MyClass myClass = ...
AnObj anObj = myClass.getObj();
anObj.changeValues();
// uh-oh, I am modifying the state of this instance of anObj which is also 
// currently being modified by Thread A
```

For MyClass to be truly thread safe you must do one of the following.

- AnObj must also guarantee thread safety (by making methods that modify its state thread-safe)
- AnObj must be immutable. That is, if you need to modify the state of AnObj you must create new instance of AnObj to hold the new state.
- The getter for AnObj must not directly expose MyClass's instance of AnObj, but a rather return a copy of that instance.